# Mule ESB and Mainframe integration possible solutions

Tags: mule, esb, mainframe, zos, cics

i am trying to connect mainframe from MuleESB we have CICS regions but i am not sure how useful CICS regions to connect and do we need to connect MQ to intgrate with Mainframe. is thr any way with out connecting MQ can we connect mainframes

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191632/which-is-proven-solution-to-connect-mainframe-and-java-which-is-best-in-mq-ser) might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

CICS itself is capable of being connected to using many different transports, including MQ and HTTP. Within those transports, CICS also supports many data formats, including SOAP for Web Services, JSON, binary, and so on.

It'll depend on your exact setup at your organisation as to which have been enabled, so you'll need to find out which transports are available for you to use and which data formats they're talking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IBM's WebSphere MQ on your mainframe, you will find it easy to communicate to your mainframe CICS transactions using the standard JMS component in Mule...we do this all the time using ActiveMQ, which is very familiar to any Mule developer. You will need a JMS "bridge" to connect Active MQ to WebSphere MQ - see [ActiveMQ bridge connector to WebSphereMQ without using XML config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476063/activemq-bridge-connector-to-webspheremq-without-using-xml-config).

Once you have connectivity, there are a lot of alternatives as to the various data formats and message payloads. As Ben Cox says, you have a bewildering array of choices, from raw application objects to XML, SOAP, JSON and so forth. Most of what you use at this level will probably depend on whether you're connecting to existing applications, or building new software that you can control.

If you're comfortable extending Mule using it's Connector Factory APIs, you should be able to encapsulate most of the information in a way that's Mule-friendly. We do this today in several large systems and it works quite well overall.